# Aligning images inside divs

Tags: css, html, image

I'm trying to fit three images inside a div, but I'm having trouble getting them to align properly. This is what I have in mind:

[alt text http://img245.imageshack.us/img245/2016/divsf.jpg](http://img245.imageshack.us/img245/2016/divsf.jpg)

But I can't for the life of me figure this one out. Can anyone please lend a hand? Thanks!

Comment: How about posting the markup you came up with?

Comment: EDIT: This is my markup:

<div id="footercol">
<h2>Stay in touch</h2>
  <img src="images/rss.png" width="80" height="80" alt="RSS feed" />
  <img src="images/twitter.png" width="119" height="140" alt="Follow us on Twitter" />
  <img src="images/facebook.png" width="80" height="80" alt="Follow us on Facebook" />
</div><!--End footercol-->

I would post my CSS but it's a mess and it doesn't accomplish anything right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS**

```
div#container {
    width:400px;
    height: 400px;
    padding:50px;
    background: red;
}
div.leftbox {
    float: left;
    width:175px;
    height: 175px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    background: blue;
}
div.rightbox {
    float: right;
    width: 175px;
    height: 400px;
    background: yellow;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="rightbox">
        Right Image Box
    </div>
    <div class="leftbox">
        Left Image Box Top
    </div>
    <div class="leftbox">
        Left Image Box Bottom
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/tMxkX/2/

Answer (score 0):

If changing markup is allowed, I propose to wrap img 1 and 2 in another div - then it is just a matter of floating the div to the left.